# How to store REST api result in service to avoid requerying

Tags: angularjs, rest

service

```
app.factory('Notes', ['$resource', function($resource) {
    return $resource('/notes/:id', {id: '@id'}, 
        {
            'query':    {method: 'GET', params: { format: 'json'}, isArray: true},
            'update':   {method:'PUT'},
            'save':     {method:'POST'},
            'remove':   {method:'DELETE'},
            'delete':   {method:'DELETE'}
        },
        {   stripTrailingSlashes: false}

    );
}]);
```

Controller:

```
app.controller('NotesCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Notes',
                                   function($scope, $routeParams, Notes) {

    $scope.notes = Notes.query();

    Notes.query(
        function(data) {
            $scope.notes = data;
            // success handler
        }, 
        function(error) {
            alert('error')
            // error handler
        }
    );
}]);
```

If we are using Notes service in multiple controller it will fetch data again and again.

How to avoid fetching data? I want to fetch data only once and then serve same data to every controller.

Comment: have you tried cache option? Issue depends on whether you do updates to the data or not. Lots of results on this in web serch

Comment: easy way $rootScope Or Angular Cookies  or LocalStorage

Comment: @charlietfl, thanks for response. I tried cache option. But it doesn't seems to work when i do add/update to data.